# Swift: Check if UIWebView Zoomed-In or Zoomed-out

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiwebview, swift3

I have a **UIWebview** in which I want **gesture recognizers** to work only when the page is **not zoomed-in**.

When a user **zooms-in** on a page, I want to **remove** the **recognizers**.

Similarly, when the webView is **zoomed-out** to the **default level**, I want to **re-add** the **recognizers**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Gesture Recognizers are for navigation b/w pages rather than zooming.

Answer (score 2):

No need Gesture use this for zoom in and zoom out

```
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = true                 
self.webView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Comment: I've added recognizers for navigation b/w pages rather than zooming

Comment: If you added gesture than identified your zooming scale how much further zooming scale. If zooming scale change than you can use your logic